# Where do I set the major and subtype guid in a pin

Tags: c++, directshow

Using GraphStudioNext it shows that my filter output pin has a major- and subtype of GUID_NULL.
Where do I set it in code in c++?

Comment: Is this for IMpeg2Demultiplexer?

Comment: It's for the avi mux. It accepts media with major type of MEDIATYPE_STREAM and subtype of MEDIATYPE_Avi

Comment: Not familiar with that, but with mpeg you create a [AM_MEDIA_TYPE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373477(v=vs.85).aspx) and pass that to `CreateOutputPin`.

Comment: I don't think i can access the connected filter directly, but only through its pin

Answer (score 1):

According to MSDN, [IPin::QueryAccept](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> A return value of S_OK indicates that the pin will accept the media type, either on the next sample, or after a pin reconnection.

So, you can create a new AM_MEDIA_TYPE and pass it to IPin::QueryAccept.

Answer (score 0):

Look in MSDN for AMOVIESETUP_FILTER, this structure describes your filter for its registration in the system. It contains some AMOVIESETUP_PIN which describe your pins and contain some AMOVIESETUP_MEDIATYPE structs that describe major and sub types of your filter's pins. This is the place to put correct types if you want GraphEdits to show them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear what you're doing here (e.g. what your filter is and whether you're trying to connect it to the avi mux input or output) but some general points:

- Before connection the pin properties in GraphStudioNext show the media types offered by the filter. In a C++ filter using the baseclasses this done by overriding [GetMediaType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368709(v=vs.85).aspx) - the exact class depends on which filter/pin classes you are using. If you haven't overriden this you typically see no media types offered. Some filters will accept input with GUID_NULL/GUID_NULL media type but it's unlikely to give sensible results (e.g the Avi Mux perhaps).
- Some filters support offering media types from input pins but this is uncommon.
- After connection the pin properties in GraphStudioNext show the media type of the connection.
- If you're connecting to the Avi Mux input pin you need to select the media type carefully - GraphStudioNext has a mode to support this. The Avi Mux is fairly promiscuous and will wrap most DirectShow media types and samples in an AVI container though the results may not be usable if the media types are unusual. This does make AVI files a useful general purpose container file for testing though. Beware of AVI files unexpectedly reconnecting their input pins though - they will typically reconnect at the first media type offered by the output pin.
- The Avi Mux output pin expects to connect to an input pin that supports random access via [IStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380034(v=vs.85).aspx) like the file writer rather than passing data via media samples. In GraphStudioNext you can use the analyzer file writer filter and see the writing process in the property page.
- If you just want to concatenate all the output sample data to a file you can do this with the Microsoft sample dump filter. This is useful for diagnosing audio problems, for example. It's also one possible starting point for writing your own file based renderer.
- If you have particular problem with GraphStudioNext add an issue on the Google Code site. The devs are listening!